# Using reverse url lookup in django template with keyword arguements

Tags: python, django

I would like to use the reverse url lookup available in a django template using keyword arguments instead of positional ones.

I have it working using positional arguments just fine as such:

HTML:

```
    <a href="{% url 'download' customer.pk %}">download</a>
```

URL:

```
    (r'^generator/download/(?P<customer_id>\d+)/$', 'generator.views.send_file', name='download'),
```

View definition:

```
    def send_file(request, customer_id):
```

The problem is that I am noticing a security flaw in that now anyone can simply enter as a url like:

```
    /generate/download/<any number>/
```

and download a file that is meant only for someone else.  I understand that this risk might be able to be mitigated by using user permissions etc, but I still would like to add another layer of security just in case.  Maybe I am wrong in my thinking that a keyword argument is safer in this regard because it is not simply available to be passed in the url... But that is what I am thinking.

The code as I think it should work looks like:

HTML:

```
    <a href="{% url 'download' customer_id=customer.pk %}">download</a>
```

URL:

```
    (r'^generator/download/$', 'generator.views.send_file', name='download'),
```

View definition:

```
    def send_file(request, customer_id=None):
        customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, pk=customer_id)
        ... other code
```

meaning if /generate/download/ is entered in the url (without the accompanying kwarg) it would just give them 404.

but I am getting the following error when I try to use this code:

```
Reverse for 'download' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'customer_id': 33}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['generator/download/$']
```

I'm sure it is something silly that I simply passed over in the django url dispatcher docs, or perhaps it is in the way I am defining my view (perhaps I need **kwargs as the argument?) but I can't seem to find it for the life of me.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to user `request.user` in your view, to get the current user. Take a look at [Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user)

Comment: use session to store your customer_id or for more security use Authentication https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/

Comment: I have never used the session.  Though I would like to learn, I am finding it quite cumbersome finding ways to pass things from view to view.  I have been told that using the session can be tricky and create unpredictable results between page closes/opens etc... any merit to those claims @slim_ch?

Comment: @trnsnt I have not implememted users yet... I will eventually for now I just have an arbitrary data model I am calling customer here.

Comment: if your customer have to auth before access to Downlod in this case use authentication to create  session for y customer were you store his data safely and if he logout his session will be delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is unfortunately completely wrong. Keyword arguments *are* passed in the URL, they are simply sent to the view function in a different way - in kwargs instead of args.

The simplest way to solve your problem is just to check the user in the download function itself.

```
def download(request, pk):
    obj = Download.objects.get(pk)
    if obj.customer_id != request.user.id:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, as this will be a one to many relationship with users I will have to add a foreign key to my data model to make this check then.  Looks like I will need to dig into the auth_user portion sooner than later...

Comment: incorrect assumptions aside. can you perhaps point me to where my code is wrong for future reference?  how do I tell url.py that I will be expecting kwargs for a given url?  The error message above is indicative that somewhere that must be defined, I just don't know where that is.

Comment: Your original URL definition was correct for kwargs.